# Boot Linux Mint 19.3 with WinXP boot manager

Tags: boot, windows-xp, linux-mint

I use WinXP installed on a SATA HD and wanted to try Linux Mint 19.3 to see whether I like it. I created two partitions on a separate old IDE HD of the same PC, first partition (41 GB) for Linux, second (39 GB, NTFS) for data that I want to be visible from Win. I disconnected the SATA HD and installed Linux, formatting its partition as ext4, and everything is OK. Now I would like to add Linux to the boot menu of WinXP (I'd prefer to avoid GRUB, I'm not sure that I'll keep Linux and don't want to mess with the MBR of the XP disk). I tried making a file with a copy of the Linux boot sector and adding that to boot.ini as suggested in some sites, but no luck. Anyone knows whether what I want is possible, and how to do it?
Many thanks,
Ugo

P.S.: plan is to switch to something different from XP, but I have to learn it first, and understand how to do the things I want to do... in the meanwhile, I have to keep doing my work, for which XP is still OK.

Comment: Get rid of XP (long dead and insecure as a base system) and install Linux natively. That should work depending on the age of the hardware

Comment: XP does not recognize Linux filesystems, so you still need a bootloader in the MBR for Linux. Use grub or preferably just dump XP. There is no reason whatsoever to use XP unless you have software that is absolutely required and does not work on anything newer. XP was great, but is bad now.

Comment: According to this [Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153985) post NTLDR can't call Linux .  You can though install either SysLinux or Grub legacy to partition VBR rather than the MBR though and chainload NTLDR.  I use EasyBCD to chainload Syslinux installed on the partition vbr from Windows 10 (it copies the VBR data to C drive).  According to their documentation XP is supported but I didn't try it - see [NeoSmart Knowledgebase](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/adding-entries/#LinuxBSD) for instructions on adding the Linux entry.